# How to copy a file in using a string that has %UserProfile% in C#

Tags: c#, copy, profile, user-profile

I am trying to copy a file using this -

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar"))
            try
            {                  
                File.Copy(@"C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar", @"C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Documents\MinecraftBackup\minecraft.jar", true);
            }
```

and it won't work unless I change %UserProfile% to my actual username, how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar
```

try

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
             @".minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar")
```

In fact, any time you see "`C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\`", you should use "`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`".

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = @"C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\";
var s2 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(s);
```

s2 has expanded data

Answer (score 0):

The `%userprofile%` variable includes the full path, all the way back to the root of the drive.

```
C:\Windows\System32>echo %userprofile%
C:\Users\[myusername]
```

Comment: This is going to be used on other peoples computers so I dont believe that will work